# How to extract files which match more than two pattern?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

Suppose I have myarchive.tar

```
  myarchive.tgz/file1.txt
               /folder1/node1.txt
               /folder2/node2.txt 
               /folder3/file3.txt
               /dir/node3.txt
               /file2.txt
```

How to extract files which match two patterns i.e `"folder"` & `"node"`.
So that I will get node1.txt and node2.txt
I have tried wildcards but I only know how to execute it with one pattern.
i.e. `tar --wildcards -zvf myarchive.tgz -x "*folder*"`
or
`tar --wildcards -zvf myarchive.tgz -x "*node*"`
but it gives only half answer.
Is there any way to get full answer by writing a single script.

Comment: `only half answer` - what exactly is a "half answer"? What exactly does each command give? You want `tar -xzvf arch.tar.gz "*folder*" "*node*"`?

Comment: `tar --wildcards -zvf myarchive.tgz -x "*folder*"` gives node1.txt, node2.txt, file3.txt
`tar --wildcards -zvf myarchive.tgz -x "*node*"` gives node1.txt, node2.txt, node3.txt
I only want to extract files which has both `folder` and `node` in it.
i.e. node1.txt and node2.txt

Comment: I want `/folder1/node1.txt` and `/folder2/node2.txt`

Comment: Please have a look at `man tar` and `man bash`, section pattern matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just merge globulations together:

```
tar --wildcards -xvf myarchive.tgz '*folder*node*'
tar --wildcards -xvf myarchive.tgz './folder[0-9]*/node[0-9]*.txt'
```

Comment: Do you really need the flag `--wildcards`?

Comment: Without it tar says `tar: Pattern matching characters used in file names`
`tar: Use --wildcards to enable pattern matching,  or --no-wildcards to suppress this warning`. I wonder what that "default" in man means, it looks like `no-wildcards` is the default. GNU tar 1.29 on repl

Comment: tar 1.29 on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) works. 1.29 on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SnarlingGleamingLoops) does not work. 1.31 on my archlinux does not work. 1.29 on my opensuse does not work. Magic. I am testing with simple `tar -cvf a.tar /dev/null ; tar -xvf a.tar '*null*' ; rm a.tar`. Och [it changed](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Changes.html) `Therefore, starting from version 1.15.91, GNU tar no longer uses globbing by default.` :)